# Rails API Routing issue (only in production with nginx + unicorn)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn

i've developed an api with rails, and in localhost everything was ok.
but when my api is at prod server, i got errors with my routes...

here is the scenario:

- my prod server is configured with nginx and unicorn
- im using subdomain and versions in my routes (api.servername/v1/resource)

routes.rb file:

```
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
  scope module: 'api' do
    namespace :v1 do

      resources :tests, param: :name do
        member do
          get 'perform'
        end
      end
      resources :jobs

    end
  end
end
```

nginx conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.server.com.br;

  # Application root, as defined previously
  root rails_public_path;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://appname;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    proxy_read_timeout 1800;
  }}
```

when i run `rake routes` in prod, my routes are there, but unicorn returns the 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a TLD problem. It's not only on Unicorn.
If you config your /etc/hosts with the same domain, you will get the same error.

Removing the constraint of subdomain in the routes.rb works as expected.

routes.rb file:

```
# constraints subdomain: 'api' do
scope module: 'api' do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :tests, param: :name do
      member do
        get 'perform'
      end
    end
    resources :jobs
  end
end
# end
```